# obtener valor de varios botones con JQUERY

Tags: jquery

hola chicos tengo en total 10 botones el cual tienen un valor que quiero extraer su valor con un click dependiendo cual sea el voton pinchado lo estoy haciendo con jquery pero no se que estoy haciendo mal aqui mi codigo:

```js
 
 $("#evaluate button").click(function(){

        alert($(this).val());

   })
```

```html
 <div id="evaluate">
      <button value="1"><b>1</b> </button>
      <button value="2"><b>2</b> </button>
      <button value="3"><b>3</b> </button>
      <button value="4"><b>4</b> </button>
      <button value="5"><b>5</b> </button>
      <button value="6"><b>6</b> </button>
      <button value="7"><b>7</b> </button>
      <button value="8"><b>8</b> </button>
      <button value="9"><b>9</b> </button>
      <button value="10"><b>10</b> </button>
    </div>
```

gracias cualquier ayuda la agradesco mucho

Comment: tu código es funcional, solo te hace falta llamar a jquery justo antes de la etiqueta script donde hiciste tu código, lo acabo de probar y sirve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te comento que probé tu código y es funcional sobre lo que solicitas, lo que debes tener en cuenta es que primero debe ir el llamado a jquery y posterior el script con el que obtienes el valor mira

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="evaluate">
      <button id="val1" value="1"><b>1</b> </button>
      <button id="val2" value="2"><b>2</b> </button>
      <button id="val3" value="3"><b>3</b> </button>
      <button id="val4" value="4"><b>4</b> </button>
      <button id="val5" value="5"><b>5</b> </button>
      <button id="val6" value="6"><b>6</b> </button>
      <button id="val7" value="7"><b>7</b> </button>
      <button id="val8" value="8"><b>8</b> </button>
      <button id="val9" value="9"><b>9</b> </button>
      <button id="val10" value="10"><b>10</b> </button>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

<script>
     $("#evaluate button").click(function(){

        alert($(this).val());

   })
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner una clase común a todos los botones y detectar en cual haces click directamente.

```js
 
 $(".class-button").click(function(){

        alert($(this).val());

   })
```

```html
 <div id="evaluate">
      <button class="class-button" id="val1" value="1"><b>1</b> </button>
      <button class="class-button" id="val2" value="2"><b>2</b> </button>
      <button class="class-button" id="val3" value="3"><b>3</b> </button>
      <button class="class-button" id="val4" value="4"><b>4</b> </button>
      <button class="class-button" id="val5" value="5"><b>5</b> </button>
      <button class="class-button" id="val6" value="6"><b>6</b> </button>
      <button class="class-button" id="val7" value="7"><b>7</b> </button>
      <button class="class-button" id="val8" value="8"><b>8</b> </button>
      <button class="class-button" id="val9" value="9"><b>9</b> </button>
      <button class="class-button" id="val10" value="10"><b>10</b> </button>
    </div>
```